# Possible to view JSON data from AJAX load

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firebug

I just wonder if it possible to use tools like Chromes inspector or Firefox Firebug to view JSON data that has been loaded with AJAX?

I have searched, but I can't find any info about this. I also looked inside the Network tab in Chrome, but without any progress.

It would be interesting to be able to view this data, or is this made impossible due to some security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the 'response' and 'preview' in chromes Network Tab. If the request returns JSON data then the preview tab automatically formats it for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't find the options 'response' and 'preview',  where can I find them?

Comment: If you go into the network tab, once you click on any of the network requests on the left hand side, it should appear on the right. If you still can't find it post a screenshot of your chrome developer window and I will point it out to you.

Comment: OK, I found it finally! I didn't have the same view as your image from the beginning when I clicked the XHR button.

Comment: Awesome! another pro tip is to hit F12 to go to the developer menu and then hit F1 (this brings up the settings for the dev tools). There should be a checkbox that says Log XMLHttpRequests. This essentially should log all of your XHR requests directly onto the console. Makes it a little bit easier. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info!